# request.getRequestURI always returns "/error"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, interceptor

In a webapp I'm building using Spring Boot & MVC and am trying to deny access to for all URL's except /signin for users that are not logged in. To achieve this I've setup an implementation of HandlerInterceptor where the preHandler should route all non-valid requests to the /signin page.

The setup:

**LoginViewController**

```
package com.controller;

import com.model.UserDao;
import com.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
@SessionAttributes("username")
public class LoginViewController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showLoginForm(){
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView verifyLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView;
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        // if login fails, set reload login page
        if (userService.verifyUserLogin(username,request.getParameter("password")) == null){
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
            modelAndView.addObject("login_failed", true);
        } else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**AccessInterceptor**

```
package com.spring.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AccessInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());

        try {
            if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/signin")) {
                if (request.getSession()
                        .getAttribute("username") == null) {
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/signin");
                    return false;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                           ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Post-handle");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After completion handle");
    }
}
```

**WebApplicationConfig**

```
package com.spring;

import com.spring.interceptor.AccessInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(
                new AccessInterceptor()).
                addPathPatterns("/**").
                excludePathPatterns("/signin/**").
                excludePathPatterns("/static/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

**WebApplicationInitializer**

```
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(WebApplicationConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(MyWebAppInitializer.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.css");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.eot");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.svg");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.ttf");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.woff");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.map");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.js");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.ico");
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that the `System.out.println(request.getRequestURI())` in AccessInterceptor always prints `/error`. So the request is always redirected even when calling `/signin`. Another interesting thing is that no CSS or other static resources are rendered, even with the dispacher mapping configured.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue... All path matchers are not working because of this(I think). Did you found a solution?

Comment: Hi there! It's been a while since, but as far as I can remember I never really resolved the issue. I think I completely moved away from using a MVC structure and did it in a RESTful fashion. Sorry I can't help, but if you find the answer, please share. I'm very interested still :)

Comment: I found out that spring-security was the issue, but I still don't know what the exact issue is... I am making a RESTful application.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem，in WebLogIntercept(your MyWebAppInitializer) class 
I solved this problem using the following code

add this two func

```
    private Class getClassByName(Class classObject, String name){
        Map<Class,List<Field>> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
        Class returnClass = null;
        Class tempClass = classObject;
        while (tempClass != null) {
            fieldMap.put(tempClass,Arrays.asList(tempClass .getDeclaredFields()));
            tempClass = tempClass.getSuperclass();
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Class,List<Field>> entry: fieldMap.entrySet()){
            for (Field f : entry.getValue()) {
                if(f.getName().equals(name)){
                    returnClass = entry.getKey();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return returnClass;
    }

    private Object findCoyoteRequest(Object request)  throws Exception {
        Class a = getClassByName(request.getClass(),"request");
        Field request1 = a.getDeclaredField("request");
        request1.setAccessible(true);
        Object b = request1.get(request);
        if(getClassByName(b.getClass(),"coyoteRequest") == null){
            return findCoyoteRequest(b);
        }else{
            return b;
        }
```

and use this code

```
Object a = findCoyoteRequest(request);
Field coyoteRequest = a.getClass().getDeclaredField("coyoteRequest");
coyoteRequest.setAccessible(true);
Object b = coyoteRequest.get(a);

Field uriMB = b.getClass().getDeclaredField("uriMB");
uriMB.setAccessible(true);
MessageBytes c = (MessageBytes)uriMB.get(b);
System.out.println(c.getString());
```

c.getString() is realuri

my english is not good，Hope useful

Comment: working! but need to know why?

Answer (score 0):

if you missing your payload, the api url couldn't recognize. at least put something[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disabling CFR worked for me
See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same function to implement as you. And I finally found that there was nothing wrong with this function. The "/error" request actually exists, maybe sent by the servlet container or whatever(i don't know). It exists to show you the exception on the browser.
When I put "/error" to my white-list(I also put paths like "/login" which don't need the authority), the `e.printStackTrace();` information just show on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought that 「request.getServletPath();」 could not get the path, but later I found that because of the CorsConfiguration problem, I would get "/error" because of the following error: "When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value " *" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead."

My fix:

//corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");

Change to:

corsConfiguration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");

Answer (score -3):

sometimes,you can try rebuild project,here is my code：

`if(request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/user/")) {return true;}`

it always return "`/error`"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Where is the solution for the question? Its working for you but not for him and rebuild doesn't solve the problem